# C2DM in C++ NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-c2dm

Is it possible to register and receive C2DM messages from the Android NDK in C++?

All the C2DM examples on Google's site are from the Java SDK. I checked through the NDK docs and could find no mention of C2DM.

I am relatively certain there is no way to do this. Does anyone know differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely. The receiving end for C2DM needs to be implemented as a Java class that derives from BroadcastReceiver and is listed in the manifest. AFAIK, you cannot create a brand new Java class entirely in NDK - you need a Java file, even if it has nothing but `native` method declarations.

From there, it's a matter of overriding BroadcastReceiver methods - primarily `onReceive()`. That you can do in NDK.

And you won't, most likely, find any examples.